How to transfer SPL token to a PDA from Phantom or Solflare
As the title, I can not transfer token to a initialized PDA from the wallet. It say errors on Phantom and Solflare:


PDA address: https://solscan.io/account/FjwkExgKxJL68zDbYoTCZUqQjpPnWSN47EUujoJ7j23J?cluster=devnet
Thanks.
Edit
After doing some experiment, I have some conclusion:

To send SPL token to a PDA, you have to initialize the associated token account of that PDA, then just send to the ATA account address.

Note: You have to initialize the ATA first. Because if you send SPL token to a uninitialized ATA, It will initialize another ATA of the uninitialized ATA and transfer SPL token to it.


